# What's a better way to get the result from async 1st function on the 3rd function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Although I now i could get a variable outside funcs to be microsite or change the callback on the 2nd function to be `function(err, result) { cb(cb, result, microsite)}` I would like to know a better option than the ones suggested above. Here is my code:

```
var funcs = [
  function(cb){
    Microsite.findOne({_id: id1}, cb);  
  },
  function(microsite, cb){
    VideoAccount.findOne({_id: id2}, cb);
  },
  function(videoAccount, cb) {
    execute(microsite, videoAccount, cb);
  });

  async.waterfall(funcs, function(err, result){...});
```

Comment: I think you should take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420019/asyncjs-bypass-a-function-in-a-waterfall-chain and also here:  https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [auto](https://github.com/caolan/async#auto) function:

```
async.auto({

    microSite: function(cb) {
        Microsite.findOne({_id: id1}, cb);
    },

    videoAccount: function(cb) {
        VideoAccount.findOne({_id: id2}, cb);
    },

    thirdFunction: ["microSite", "videoAccount", function(results, cb) {
        execute(results.microSite, results.videoAccount, cb);
    }]

}, function(error, result) {...});
```

where the final `result` is an object of the form:

```
result = {
    microSite, 
    videoAccount, 
    thirdFunction
}
```

**NOTE**: the parameters in the third function are dependent upon your version:

1.x is `function(cb, results)`

2.x is `function(results, cb)`

Personally, I use auto everywhere in place of parallel, waterfall, and series. It makes it easier to refactor in the future if your code ever changes to your current need.

Comment: The auto method is awesome. Thanks!